# How to make a keybind in vim, that lets the user insert, the repeats the insertion?

Tags: vim, latex, vi, keymapping

I would like to make a keybind that will let the user type something in insert mode, then goes to a different line, and puts what the user typed there. The purpose of this is for LaTeX `\begin` and `\end`. This is what I have so far:

```
autocmd Filetype tex inoremap `d \begin{}<CR><++><CR>\end{}<esc>2kf{a
```

At the end, `a` lets the user type in the `\begin` field, and I want to make it so that, when I exit insert mode, what I typed is put into the `\end` field. I honestly have no idea how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the [vi.se] stack for questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden No. This is on topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly hard to do for a single mapping.

If you really want to roll your own, I think the simplest approach I can suggest here is to prompt the user for the environment type (with [`input()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#input%28%29)) and then use that name twice when inserting the block.

This should work:

```
function! LatexEnvironment()
    let name = input('Environment name: ')
    return "\\begin{".name."}\r\\end{".name."}\<C-o>O"
endfunction
autocmd Filetype tex inoremap <expr> `d LatexEnvironment()
```

---

A much better approach here is to use a **snippet engine**.

It's typically very easy to support multiple fields with repetitions and you can even set default values for fields in a snippet engine.

For example, in [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), you can use the following snippet:

```
snippet "\\?b(egin)?" "begin{} / end{}" br
\begin{${1:something}}
    ${0:${VISUAL}}
\end{$1}
endsnippet
```

Which is in fact a [standard snippet](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/3805db7f2d539ef5c92b54263a97355bfb1609df/UltiSnips/tex.snippets#L47,L51) you can find in the [honza/vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) library.

Answer (score 4):

Stop this madness and use all these below:

- [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets)
- [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)
- most importantly, [VimTex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex).

Comment: Great advice to using vimtex on TeX + LaTeX files! It's one of the best plug-ins in Vim!